# Evaluate the limit, if it exists

Tags: calculus

> *In Exercises 5-34, evaluate the limit, if it exists. If not, determine whether the one side limit exists (finite or infinite).*
>
> 26. $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}\right)$$

So I'm trying to get $x$ out of the denominator, so I tried combining:

$\require{cancel}$

$$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x-1}}$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x-1}}{-x^2}$$

But I can't go any further.

Comment: Is the expression defined for values of $x$ that are slightly bigger than $0$? If not, then the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: The second fraction namely $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}$ is not defined on small neighborhoods of $0$. so does not make sense to talk about existence.

Comment: First try substituting $x=0$ into the given expression.  This won't give you the answer (actually, if you're lucky it will) but it will give you some idea of the difficulties you have to deal with.

Comment: Are you sure you rationalized the denominator correctly? If I'm not mistaken, that last line should read $\frac{(x-1)\sqrt{x}-x\sqrt{x-1}}{x(x-1)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit does not exist. The function is only defined for values of $x>1$.

However, consider:

$$\lim_{x\to 1^+}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}\right) = -\infty$$

**Proof:**

Notice that as $x\to 1^+$, the left term $\to 1$ while the right term increases without bound (that is, the right term $\to\infty$).

$$\lim_{x\to1^+}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}\right)$$
$$\left(\lim_{x\to1^+}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right) - \left(\lim_{x\to1^+}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}\right)$$
$$=1-\infty$$
$$=-\infty$$

(Pardon my abuse of notation.)

You can verify this graphically.

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/7nvokdtmev

[image: A graph of the function 1/sqrt{x} - 1/sqrt{x-1} shows that the output decreases indefinitely as the input approaches 1 from the right.]

---

One more thing, I wanted to have a look at your attempt to combine fractions. This does not affect the answer above.

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x-1}}$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}-\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{x-1}$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}\cdot\frac{x-1}{x-1}-\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{x-1}\cdot\frac{x}{x}$$
$$\frac{(x-1)\sqrt{x}-x\sqrt{x-1}}{x(x-1)}$$